# Как реализовать нажатие кнопки назад во фрагменте в котором находится WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Проблема в том что реализовать реализовал, но из приложения не выходит.

Код из MainActivity:

```js
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        OnBackPressedListener backPressedListener = null;
        for (Fragment fragment: fm.getFragments()) {
            if (fragment instanceof  OnBackPressedListener) {
                backPressedListener = (OnBackPressedListener) fragment;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (backPressedListener != null) {
            backPressedListener.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Интерфейс:

```js
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    public void onBackPressed();
}
```

И мой фрагмент:

```js
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        webView.goBack();
    }
```

Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей? Или есть какие идеи?

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы `WebView` отлистал назад все страницы, а потом закрылась активность?

Comment: Да! Совершенно верно!

Comment: Думаю нужно изменить null на первый переход WebView. Только вот как его записать не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Методом [`canGoBack()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#canGoBack()) проверяем есть ли у `WebView` предыдущая страница и переходим, если нет закрываем активность.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
    else
        getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!